# Julia error: no method haskey(Dict{String,Dict{String,String}},ASCIIString)

Tags: julia

I'm trying to test out the Winston plotting engine in Julia. I installed the package but I'm getting some errors now when I try to compile one of the examples:

```
> julia example1.jl
Warning: could not import Base.haskey into Inifile
Warning: could not import Graphics.set_source into Color
ERROR: no method haskey(Dict{String,Dict{String,String}},ASCIIString)
 in read at /Users/thinkpad20/.julia/IniFile/src/IniFile.jl:41
 in read at /Users/thinkpad20/.julia/IniFile/src/IniFile.jl:67
 in anonymous at /Users/thinkpad20/.julia/Winston/src/Winston.jl:39
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:88
 in reload_path at loading.jl:111
 in require at loading.jl:46
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:88
 in process_options at client.jl:253
 in _start at client.jl:334
at /Users/thinkpad20/.julia/Winston/src/Winston.jl:31
at /Users/thinkpad20/.julia/Winston/examples/example1.jl:3
```

can anyone tell me what's going on? It seems to be that it can't find `Base.haskey`, but I'm not sure how to address that.

Comment: I think you have an out-of-date build of Julia. Does your system still have `has`?

Answer (score 1):

Try inspecting `Base.VERSION`

`haskey` was introduced in Julia v0.2 (still pre-release as of this writing), I suspect that you are running a version 0.1.x

The real problem is inside of the Winston package. It sounds like they have their REQUIRES information set up wrong. You should file an issue here: https://github.com/nolta/Winston.jl

You can also download pre-release version of 0.2 for windows and mac here: https://code.google.com/p/julialang/downloads/list